# Can I ask for a faster reply from graduate school?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am currently a MSc student and I have applied to the same school for a PhD. I have some connections in the department, but nobody from the admissions committee.

On the admissions page, the standard procedure states that applicants shall receive an answer within 1 to 3 months from the deadline. So far, just over a month has passed.

The problem is that I have an interesting offer from a company, and is unreasonable to ask them to wait 2 more months for me to decide. Would a polite email to the official email of the admissions committee explaining this situation be perceived negatively? Is there any chance it could help speeding up a reply?

Answer (score 3):

You can ask, but it is unlikely that you will get a decision and maybe not even a reply. Processes will be followed in fairness to all candidates.

Rules probably prevent any early decision in most places.

Comment: ... depends on the place.  Some places (maybe not the US) might have several ways in which applicants could get hired.